# How to create a table with flex-direction: column;?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

My goal is to create a table with `flex-direction: column;`.

```
Ticker Price  --.--
  --   Volume    --
```

index.html

```
<div class="d-flex">
    <div class="p-1">
        Ticker
        <div id="stockSymbol" class="font-weight-bold display-4">--</div>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex flex-column p-1">
        <div class="d-flex">
            Price
            <div id="stockPrice" class="p-1 font-weight-bold display-4">--.--</div>
        </div>
        <div class="d-flex">
            Volume
            <div id="stockVolume" class="p-1">--</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

styles.css

```
.p-1 {
  padding: 1rem;
}

.d-flex {
  display: flex;
}

.flex-column {
  flex-direction: column;
}

.font-weight-bold {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.display-4 {
  font-size: 2rem;
}
```

My expected result: I can use the `text-align: center;` to make the `stockPrice` and `stockVolume` looks aligned.

My actual result: the `text-align: center;` does not affect the view.

What I've considered:

1. Use the HTML tables. Per my knowledge, it's not mobile friendly, especially if the first column direction is to below, and the 2nd and 3rd column direction is to the right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go! I used flex-direction column

I added quite a bit to the CSS, but that was just to demonstrate what the table is doing, so if you need any of the colors/margins removed; or anything changed let me know.

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
.grid2x2 {
  min-height: 60%;
  width: 60%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
}
.grid2x2 > div {
  display: flex; 
  flex-basis: calc(50% - 40px);  
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.grid2x2 > div > div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.box { margin: 3px; }
.box1 { background-color: red; }
.box2 { background-color: orange; }
.box3 { background-color: purple; }
.box4 { background-color: grey; }
```

```html
<div class="grid2x2">
  <div class="box box1"><div>Price</div></div>
  <div class="box box2"><div>--.--</div></div>
  <div class="box box3"><div>Volume</div></div>
  <div class="box box4"><div>--</div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: For those think that this is overly complicated. It does. However, this example gave enough example to use `flex-basis`. To simplify, think about `flex-wrap: wrap;` and `flex-basis: 50%;`, `flex-direction: row;`. The logic is, if 1 box equals to 50%, the third box must be in the 2nd row because the first row is filled. If you think `<div>` inside `<div>` is complicated, try to change it to `flex-basis: 100%;`. So you will only need 1 `<div>` for `Price` and 1 `<div>` for `Volume`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my take on your problem of using `flex-direction: column` to create a table. Through this approach you can use the `div class="col"` to append data columns to the right of Price-Volume column.

```css
.table {
  display: flex;
  column-gap: 5px;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: fit-content;
  width: -moz-fit-content;
}

.col {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  row-gap: 5px;
}

.col div {
  background: beige;
}

.align-center {
  /* align-self: center; */
  text-align: center;
}

.align-right {
  /* align-self: flex-end; */
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="col">
    <div class="align-center">Ticker</div>
    <div class="align-center">--</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="align-center">Price</div>
    <div class="align-center">Volume</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="align-right">--.--</div>
    <div class="align-right">--</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="table">
  <div class="col">
    <div class="align-center">Ticker</div>
    <div class="align-center">--</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="align-center">Price</div>
    <div class="align-center">Volume</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="align-right">98.56</div>
    <div class="align-right">20</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="align-right">72.03</div>
    <div class="align-right">13</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is exactly why I don't use `<table>`. I believe this will make the code harder to read if you separate the `Price` with the `stockPrice` on different element parent.